# undefined reference for overloaded cout

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors, cout, friend

I was trying if I could replace my code for 2-, 3- and 4--dimensional vectors into 1 class, so instead of having `vec2<T>`, `vec3<T>` and `vec4<T>`, use `vecN<typenameT,unsignedS>`.

That seems to work well but the overloaded `cout` function for printing the vectors gives an `undefined reference` error. I cannot see what I'm doing differently than the usual:

(minimised) class `vectors.hpp`:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<ranges>

template <typename T, unsigned S>
class vecN {
  template <typename U> friend std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& out, const vecN<U,S>& v);
  template <typename U> friend std::istream& operator>> ( std::istream&  in,       vecN<U,S>& v);
protected:
  std::vector<T> 
  data;
public:
  vecN ( T* xyz ): data ( S ) { std::copy (xyz, xyz+S, data.begin() ); }
};

// non-members of vecN for vecN
template <typename T, unsigned S>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const vecN<T,S>& v) { 
    out << "( ";
    std::copy(v, std::ostream_iterator<char>(out, ", "));
    out << "\b\b )"; // use two ANSI backspace characters '\b' to overwrite final ", "
    return out; 
}

template <typename T, unsigned S>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in , vecN<T,S> &v) { 
    for ( auto i : std::views::iota(0u, S) )
        in >> v.data[i]; 
    return in;
}

// aliases for 2-, 3- and 4-dimensional vectors
template <typename T>
using vec2 = vecN<T,2>;

template <typename T>
using vec3 = vecN<T,3>;

template <typename T>
using vec4 = vecN<T,4>;
```

Test file `main.cpp`:

```
#include "vectors.hpp"
int main() {  
  float v[2] = { 10, 20 };
  vec2<float> v2_1 ( v );  
  std::cout << "vector v2_1 \n" << v2_1 << "\n";  
  return 0;  
}
```

When I compile them with:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -o test main.cpp vectors.hpp
```

then I get the error

```
in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `std::ostream& operator<< <float>(std::ostream&, vecN<float, 2u> const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But the compiled code for this vector type (float values, size 2) should end up in the `test` binary, shouldn't it? The types and values are determined correctly, but it does not seem to include the code?

Comment: your friend declaration is for a function with a single template parameter but your definition has two template parameters so doesn't match

Comment: Ah thanks! I had good hopes it would be easy -- not sure how I came by the idea that I could "re-use" S as the 2nd parameter, while having to use a new one instead of T...